# Entity Framework 6 Using Lambda GroupBy on a joined table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I have two tables, `Drivers` and `ViewDrivers` that I have joined together using the following lambda expression in Entity Framework 6.

```
var inAppDriverList = context.ViewDrivers
.Select(dv => new { dv.TerminalCode, dv.EmployeeId })
.Join(
          context.Drivers,
          d => d.EmployeeId,
          dv => dv.EmployeeId,
          (d, dv) => new { d, dv }
      ))
.OrderBy(dv => dv.TerminalCode)
.GroupBy(dv => dv.TerminalCode
.ToList();
```

It does give me the data that I am expecting to get, but I when I try to Sort and Group the list by the TerminalCode using `GroupBy` and `OrderBy`, I cannot get it to work correctly. I have tried everything I can think of, with no luck.

I am only having this issue when I am trying to sort a joined table so I am guessing there is something small that I am missing. I would greatly appreciate any help in getting those statements to Group and Sort by the `TerminalCode` field.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `x => x.dv.TerminalCode` instead of `dv => dv.TerminalCode` since your `Join` is creating an anonymous class with `dv` and `d` as properties?

Comment: juhar - That was it exactly.... Thank you very much. Please post this as the answer and I will select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of your `Join` will be a sequence of the anonymous class that you created with

```
(d, dv) => new { d, dv }
```

So when you try to order and group you need a lambda like

```
x => x.dv.TerminalCode
```

That or specify the values of `dv` in the anonymous class

```
(d, dv) => new { d, dv.TerminalCode, dv.EmployeeId  }
```

With that option you then wouldn't need the `Select` before the `Join`.  Additionally if you don't need all the columns in `Drivers` you can also specify them as well thus reducing the amount of data that your query has to return.